# Проблема отправки данных из java сервера к websocket клиенту на javascript

Tags: java

Всем привет! У меня проблема, уже два дня копаюсь, но так и не решил. Есть сервер на джаве, и есть клиент на скрипте. Проблема в том, что у меня не получается оправить сообщение от сервера к клиенту, хотя когда я отправляю ответные данные для соединения клиенту при подключении - все работает(соединение есть), а далее не могу ничего отправить или принять.

Код сервера:

```
 public class Main {
    static List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1340);

        while (true) {
            final Socket client = server.accept();
            Client s = new Client(client);
            clients.add(s);
            getConnect(clients.get(clients.indexOf(s)));

            for (Client c:clients
                 ) {
                c.sendMassege("YOU LALKA!!!");//уже не работает
            }
        }
    }
    static void getConnect(Client client) throws Exception {
        String data = new Scanner(client.in,"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\r\\n\\r\\n").next();

        Matcher get = Pattern.compile("^GET").matcher(data);
        if (get.find())
        {
            Matcher match = Pattern.compile("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").matcher(data);
            match.find();
            String response = ("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
                    + "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                    + "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
                    + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: "
                    + DatatypeConverter
                    .printBase64Binary(
                            MessageDigest
                                    .getInstance("SHA-1")
                                    .digest((match.group(1) + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11")
                                            .getBytes()))
                    )
                    ;

            client.sendMassege(response);
        }
    }
}
class Client {
    protected Socket client;
    protected InputStream in;
    protected OutputStream out;
    public Client(Socket client) throws Exception
    {
        this.client = client;
        this.in =  client.getInputStream();
        this.out = client.getOutputStream();
    }
    protected void sendMassege(String k) throws Exception
    {
        if (k != null & k.length() > 0) {
            out.write((k+ "\r\n\r\n").getBytes(),0,(k+ "\r\n\r\n").length());
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Код клиента:

```
function connectToServerOne(){
 var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1340/");
socket.onopen = function() {
  alert("Соединение установлено.");
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
  if (event.wasClean) {
    alert('Соединение закрыто чисто');
  } else {
    alert('Обрыв соединения'); // например, "убит" процесс сервера
  }
  alert('Код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason);
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
 alert(event.data);
if(event.data == "YOU LALKA!!!")
{
socket.Send("NO YOU LALKAQ!");
}
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  alert("Ошибка " + error.message);
};
}
```

Писал до этого на С# там все очень просто в этом плане, но необходимо сделать это на Jav`e, вот здесь и споткнулся

Comment: вот хорошая библиотека с примерами https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

Comment: т.е. без сторонней библиотеки никак? спасибо за библиотеку, конечно поковыряю, но это не совсем ответ на вопрос. Вроде как мой пример работает, но я не понимаю как организовать обмен данными, ведь после "рукопожатия" стримы ничего не передают и не принимают больше. В c# эту роль выполняют сокеты и там все изи через них...

Comment: там как раз и написана серверная часть, то, что ты пытаешься сделать, библиотека это если использовать как модуль , на пракике - решение твоей проблемы. вариант для простого и зашифрованного канала.